# socket connection always failing

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, sails.js, sails.io.js

I'm writing an application that connects to a `sails` server.

This application is written with `cordova`, `angularJS` and `Ionic`.

When I launch my application in my browser (with `ionic serve`) the socket fails to connect to the server. Here is the message I get:

```
GET http://localhost:8100/socket.io/?__sails_io_sdk_version=0.11.0&__sails_io_s…sails_io_sdk_language=javascript&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1443472067762-4 404 (Not Found)
```

The server is running locally on port 1337. I tried to change the above URL to:

```
http://localhost:1337/socket.io/?__sails_io_sdk_version=0.11.0&__sails_io_s…sails_io_sdk_language=javascript&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1443472067762-4
```

and it's working.

In my code I set the URL after `sails.io.js` has been included:

```
io.sails.url = 'http://localhost:1337';
io.sails.useCORSRouteToGetCookie = false;
```

Why is it asking to `localhost:8100` and not `localhost:1337`?

When I launch this application in my mobile device (setting the url to `http://192.168.1.10:1337`) it's working correctly.

Version of `sails.io.js` is `0.11.6`, and version of `sails` is `0.11.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution (but I'm sorry I can't recall where I found it :()

The problem was that the `io.sails.url = 'http://localhost:1337';` was executed after the first JS cycle, and thus the sails socket was already loaded. (that's (from what I understood) because in some browsers if the code is in another `script` tag it is executed in another cycle)

To make it work I had to add this code before I include the sails socket script:

```
var apiHost = 'localhost';
            (function (){
                var io;
                Object.defineProperty(window, 'io', {
                    get: function (){
                        return io;
                    },
                    set: function (value){
                        var sails;
                        io = value;
                        Object.defineProperty(io, 'sails', {
                            get: function (){
                                return sails;
                            },
                            set: function (value){
                                sails = value;
                                sails.url = 'http://'+apiHost+':1337';
                                sails.useCORSRouteToGetCookie = false;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            })();
```

Comment: thanks for posting this. I've tried implementing it and still and unable to connect. With `sails.useCORSRouteToGetCookie = false;` It repeatedly tries to connect unsuccessfully. Without it fails once with `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://MY_SAILS_IP:1337/__getcookie` Any ideas?

Comment: @BradW I don't really know, but that's weird that it does not solve your issue. In my case I'm including all js files in the head tag. First I add this code (the one in my answer) as inline code, and then I include all my libs and it's working fine

Comment: @fabian do you load socket.io-client/socket.io.js? If so, when?

Comment: @BradW Yes, juste before sails socket

Comment: OK, that's the way I had it for nearly 6 months working no problem. Then it just stopped about a week ago. I load socket.io-client then sails.io.js, finally io.sails.url = http://my_sails_api_ip:1337. Now it errors; 404 'http://my_sails_api_ip:1337/__getcookie

Comment: @BradW Do you have the same version of sails client socket and sails ? I saw it was important to make it work correctly

Comment: sails is 0.11.0 on my server side. sails.io.js bower.json says version 0.11.5 on the client side

Comment: @BradW Mmh, I don't know what's wrong then, sorry :( Maybe you should ask in another question with all the details you have?

Answer (score 1):

`localhost:8100` wont work in your mobile development environment. I faced same issue and changing localhost to your workstation's ip solved the problem

Comment: Actually on my mobile it is working because changing the URL via: io.sails.url is working, but not on desktop

Comment: Yes, for desktop(simulator) you have to use local server IP, not localhost

Comment: But in desktop I'm using the localhost:1337 (which is the host of my server), but it's actually using localhost:8100 which is the server from which my app was served (with Ionic)

Comment: @FabienHenon any luck with this? I had this configuration working and it has started failing sometime in the last week.

Comment: @BradW Yes, I just found the solution! I'll add it